# Начальное и конечное значение аргумента

Tags: python

Дана функция:

```py
def plus(a):
    return a + 2
```

Как сделать так, чтобы числа в радиусе от 5 до 10 прибавлялись к двум? По типу:

```
5 + 2 = 7
6 + 2 = 9
```

и так далее

Comment: *"числа в радиусе от 5 до 10"* - это какая-то чудная терминология. Может быть *"в диапазоне"*, а не *"в радиусе"*?

Comment: for i in range(5,10,2):
        print(i)
а вообще не понятное условие для меня. можно поподробнее?

Comment: `6 + 2 = 9` но ведь `8` же? ))

Answer (score 0):

```
def plus(a):
    return a + 2

a = 5
b = 10
for i in range(a, b):
    print(plus(i))

7
8
9
10
11
```